# Why when inserting <span> using mouseover listener, does this button lose (partial) click functionality?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, listener, mouseover

I have buttons that grab button text from attributes and they work fine. The click listener works as intended.

However when I add a listener for mousover and innerhtml new button text, they stop working partially. (Only the outer edges of the buttons function normally when clicked)

I think I have narrowed it down to the `<span>` element I also add But im not sure how to stop it from breaking the button.

Button works fine with the following code:

```
if (buttonText){
buttonText = payButtons.getAttribute("button-text");
} else {
buttonText = "Support This Site";
}
payButtons.innerHTML = "<span>"+buttonText+"</span>";
```

Button is only clickable on its outer edges with the following code:

```
if (buttonText){
buttonText = payButtons.getAttribute("button-text");
payButtons.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseover);
} else {
buttonText = "Support This Site";
}

payButtons.innerHTML = "<span>"+buttonText+"</span>";



function mouseover()
{
buttonText = this.getAttribute('amount') + " " + this.getAttribute('amount-type');
this.innerHTML = "<span>"+buttonText+"</span>";
}
```

Is there anything that can be done besides removing that functionality altogether?

Live demo of the buttons (first button, upper left): https://jsfiddle.net/0ctpbuzx/6/

Comment: So it seems it might have been the css z-index setting of that span.

Hopefully this is correct.

Comment: You might also try not adding a span, just set the text of the button as the span is serving no purpose.

Comment: Adam H I actually didn't know which sections were relevant.

I posted the sections that I thought were.

Seems I solved the problem at this point but thanks for the advice.